# Strange 2.02mib unallocated space left after deleting a parttion

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I deleted volume (via Windows 7 disk management) of HddRecovery partition(manufacturer recovery) and then stretched the Main partition C: to use unallocated space. Everything looked great on Windows end, but now in Gparted, I show 2.02mib unallocated. I am still using Ubuntu LIVE from USB. I was actually going to install dual boot tonight. But first, what is the easiest way to get rid of the 2.02mb unallocated , to merge it with sda2?

I know this has been asked before, but what I am finding in search results still leaves me lost at the beginning of the tutorial/answer(ie: swap partition,move to the left, etc?).

[image: Gparted screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about it. Modern partitioning tools align on boundaries of 2048 sectors, which works out to 1MiB boundaries. More-or-less all of them align the start points, and some align the end points, too. End points may also be adjusted to handle size issues in the filesystem, which could result in sizes that are multiple of various values, depending on the filesystem and its settings. I have no idea what these values might be for NTFS, but it's entirely possible that they're forcing the partition to be sized such that there's a 2.02MiB gap at the end of the disk. Note that 2.02MiB is *puny* by the standards of your 465.76GiB disk -- it's just 0.0004235%. So don't worry about it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I was afraid if I moved forward with install, that I would not get the option to size Ubuntu's partition via the slider, because I read that Ubuntu installation is programmed to first install on UNalloacated space. 2.02 is not much, but I was afraid I'd get an error or something saying there wasn't enough room, installation failed etc.